# Can I inject google AJAX API autoload anywhere else than globally?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, google-visualization, autoload, geomap

There is this issue I am struggling with. I know that the autoload for the google visualization geomap must be in the  part of your document.

The thing is every time I reload some other pages in my application the google reloads everything and this I want to take out. So I tried taking the :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=%7B%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22visualization%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221%22%2C%22packages%22%3A%5B%22geomap%22%2C%22table%22%5D%7D%5D%7D"></script>
```

out of my global template  and inject it when the page call happens. So to only load the google API when I need it so to keep loading times to an absolute low. I want to know if this is do-able and if the google autoload MUST exist in the global  at all times.

I am using Prototype Javascript framework and here is my code to inject the autoload :

```
var element = new Element('script', {
    src: "http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=%7B%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22visualization%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221%22%2C%22packages%22%3A%5B%22geomap%22%2C%22table%22%5D%7D%5D%7D",
    type: 'text/javascript'
});

$$('head')[0].appendChild(element);
```

This keeps it out of the rest of the site but doesn't work at all. Am I thinking about this wrong or is there some possibility of me only loading the API in one place and not everywhere.

Thank you

Comment: it seems like you can use that script to do this but the autoload doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like if you do it in the template of the view you are using it works fine. Every time the template gets rendered it refreshes the page resulting in the Google API code loading.